# Django как передать список из QuerySet в select html-шаблона?

Tags: django

Получаю список провайдеров в `view.py`.  Как подставить этот список в `forms.ChoiceField` из `forms.py` и отрендерить в шаблоне?

Получаю список мерчантов в **views.py**

```
merchants = Contractors.objects.values_list('name')
```

Форма в **forms.py**

```
 class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    date1st = forms.DateField(required=False)
    date2st = forms.DateField(required=False)
    numberPhone = PhoneNumberField(region='RU', required=False)
    contractorName = forms.ChoiceField(required=False)
    status = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

UPD. `contractorName = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Contractors.objects.values_list('name'),flat=true, required=False)` - вот это помогло. Но форма не проходит валидацию: пишет, что некорректные данные введены. Как я могу видеть, на проверку приходит не выбранный вариант, а просто весь селектор...

Comment: Попробуйте `flat=True` добавить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отрендерил вручную.

```
    <select name="contractorName" class="form-control" id="id_contractorName">
<option value="" selected=""></option>
{% for contractor in contractors %}
 <option value="{{ contractor }}">{{ contractor }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите этот ответ. Советую использовать `ChoiceField`

```
contractorName = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[
    (choice.pk, choice.name) for choice in Contractors.objects.all()], required=False)
```

Comment: А почему не подходит? Что Вы собираетесь в `option value` ложить?

Comment: У меня в целом ругается на этот синтаксис, что `missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'`. Собираюсь в `value` класть только имя.